# RxJava design question: retryWhen and concat to achieve desired functionality

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

*Background:*
I have an observable that returns mock items and actual items. Mock items are used in ui while actual items are still on the way. Mock items should always arrive first to prevent accidental override of actual items in ui. The premise is that ui layer is dumb, and it does not know which items it is showing nor it's managing them in any way. So the single source of items is this observable. Simplified it looks like this.

```
    val one = Observable.fromCallable { "Mock/cached items" }
    val two = Observable.fromCallable { "Live items" }
    val result = Observable.concat(listOf(one, two))
            .subscribe {
                println(it)
            }
```

Now I want to replay this observable, because further downstream it's just one observable of many that are combined together via combineLatest() operator, hence I can't resubscribe to it individually. So, I've added replayWhen(...) after concat() and everything worked properly.

*Problem:*
Things got tricky when I needed to replay only mock items in some cases vs replaying all items in other cases. Attempt that failed:

```
    val subject1 = PublishSubject.create<Unit>()
    val subject2 = PublishSubject.create<Unit>()
    val one = Observable.fromCallable { "Mock/cached items" }.repeatWhen { subject1 }
    val two = Observable.fromCallable { "Live items" }.repeatWhen { subject2 }
    val result = Observable.concat(listOf(one, two))
            .subscribe {
                println(it)
            }
    subject1.onNext(Unit)
    subject2.onNext(Unit)
```

Obviously, it prints only mock items while live items aren't called (anytime soon:-)). This is because concat waits for onComplete from first observable, that doesn't happen because of replay operator.

Solutions, and their drawbacks:

1. Replace **concat** with **merge**. This way both observable would work, but there's no guarantee that observable **one** would fire before the observable **two**. Is there any way to achieve ordering between observables without concat?
2. Have replayWhen() after concat, to replay this result observable as a whole, but have something inside .fromCallable{} of observable **two** to know when to skip it. Not sure what could it be, as a simple flag would be unreliable and dependant on external state that may change sporadically.

Thank you for any other ideas.

Comment: your use case is still not 100% clear to me. I understand that you want to have 'placeholder'/mock item while a longer running request or process is happening. That sounds like a candidate for BehaviorSubject with default value as the mock one. But I have a feeling you have more requirements though I'm not sure what.

Comment: @Aarjav Yes, using subject resolved my problem, thank you for the hint. I guarantee ordering via using Subject.onNext() calls in specific order, and have fine grained control if I only want to emit mock items without live items, etc. You may publish your comment as an answer actually.